# Cross-Env not found on production build

Tags: express, sequelize.js, next.js, digital-ocean, cross-env

**bin/sh/:1:cross-env: not found.**

**error command failed with exit code 127**

Using nextJs with the custom express server. If I remove cross-env from the script then it is showing Express is not found

```
[2021-07-20 12:08:54] yarn run v1.22.10
[2021-07-20 12:08:54] $  cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js
[2021-07-20 12:08:55] /bin/sh: 1: cross-env: not found
[2021-07-20 12:08:55] error Command failed with exit code 127.
[2021-07-20 12:08:55] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGwjf.jpg)
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHVdN.jpg)

Comment: Please add any code or errors as properly formatted text to the question. Do _not_ use images for code.

Comment: I solved that issue.. the problem was I was not rebuilding the app. It was using the last build-cache which has no cross_env modules.